# Textfield does not show keyboard when click on the field in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Textfield does not show keyboard when clicked on the textfield in flutter?

```
  Widget _nameTextField(String hintText) {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        // border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius:  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(radius))),
        hintText: hintText,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15)),
      cursorRadius: Radius.circular(10),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      autofocus: true,
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Create"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
        // child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              _nameTextField("New text"),
            ],
          ),
        // ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Saw this somewhere else and fixed it.

CMD + Shift + K toggles connectivity of the hardware keyboard, which will open the software keyboard by default if the other one is disconnected.

CMD + K toggles the visibility of the software keyboard.